# Webpage is broken on Internet explorer

Tags: magento2, browser

I'm getting the broken webpage on internet explorer when I have set pub as a root directory. I have attached the output for your reference. Please let me know your suggestion and help me to resolve this issue.

Magento version: 2.2.3

Note: When I have removed pub as a root directory, I didn't get any error and the webpage is rendering correctly.

Comment: does it work on Chrome, Firefox & other browsers and it's *just* internet explorer?

Comment: It works fine on other browsers. I'm getting the broken page only in internet explorer.

Comment: Could you show us what you mean by broken? What error messages does it throw?